# Convert ClosedRange<String> to List in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, range

I wonder how I can convert the following `ClosedRange<String>` to `List<String>`:

```kotlin
 val letters: ClosedRange<String> = ("a".."z")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ClosedRange` knows nothing about items in the middle. It is basically a start and an end item.

The problem here is that you used strings and you should use chars. There is no meaningful answer on what strings exist between the string `"a"` and `"z"`. What about: `"hello"`? Is it between them or not? But if we discuss chars, then obviously, we know what chars exist between `'a'` and `'z'`, we can iterate over them or create a list:

```kotlin
val letters = ('a'..'z').toList()
```

Please be aware this code returns `List<Char>`, not `List<String>`. If you need strings, we can easily convert from chars:

```kotlin
val letters = ('a'..'z').map { it.toString() }
```

We don't need `toList()` anymore, because `map` implicitly converted from a range to a list.